# React-router not able to load nested pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Am just not able to make react-router load the nested pages.

I have the following configuration for React-Router

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';

import App from './components/app';
import Authors from'./components/authors/authorPage';
import About from'./components/about/aboutPage';

const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({ basename: "/" });

const Routes = () => 
{
    const routes = (
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/authors" component={Authors}/>
        </Route>
    );

    return (
    <Router history={ appHistory }>
        {routes}
    </Router>);
};

export default Routes;
```

And its getting called via links in the header page as

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';

const Header = () =>
{
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <a href="/" className="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="images/pluralsight-logo.png"/>
                </a>
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/authors">Authors</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

App component is

```
import Home from './homePage';
import Header from './common/header';

const App = () =>
{
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Home/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The root App loads just fine and I see the main root page. However, clicking on any of the link just changes the address bar to that link (`http://localhost:9005/about`) but nothing renders, the about page never loads.

In fact, if I manually enter that page (`http://localhost:9005/about`) I get the error

`Cannot GET /about`

Comment: Sounds like your server routing isn't setup correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `children` in the spot where you are expecting the routes to load.

```
const App = ({ children }) =>
{
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Home/>

                {children} <--- Route components will appear here
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Presumably you don't want to show `Home` as well as other pages at the same time, so update your route config with an `IndexRoute` so `Home` will appear on the root url.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="/authors" component={Authors}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: fantastic! thanks. Modifying the App to take props and then setting {props.Children}, whilst simultaneously setting IndexRoute solved the issue!

Comment: Ah yes, missed that in my answer. I updated it (you can drop `props` if you want using destructuring